# How to solve this calculation puzzle question?

Tags: pattern

[image]

How to solve the above puzzle? I have no particular idea to figure it out. Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: Where is this question from? All questions here from other sources must be *properly attributed* -- it's required by site policy, but it can also help us find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For each clock, first get the number the hour hand points to and then the **hour number** the minute hand points to.
>
>  For example, the first clock has hands pointing to 5 and 1 so combine them to 51 and the second clock has 12 and 3 so combine them to 123. Then just add 51 and 123.
>
>  $51+123=174$
>
>  $911+72=983$

---

Answer:

> $113 - 16 = 97$